# Embedded Browser Downloads on Local Machine but not on Windows Server c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, quickbooks-online, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to automate some functions on a web page (download an Excel document from QuickBooks online). I've got the script working fabulously on my local development machine (running Windows 8.1), but when I compiled it and ran it on our server (running Windows Server 2012 R2), it runs okay until I need to actually download the file. No prompts pop up, and the `Navigating` handler just freezes on a URL looking like the following: `https://qbo.intuit.com/c1/v82.221.1234567890123/1342890533/reports/execute?rptid=1342890533-PANDL-export-1423773529093`

This is the type of URL that gets generated when you click on the "Export to Excel" button. Unfortunately, there isn't an easy URL with a ".xls" at the end, or else I'd handle that in the `Navigating` event.

I'm running Visual Studio 2013, and I'm using the `webBrowser` control in a Windows Form application as an embedded browser. I'll attach code if you feel it's necessary.

My main question is this:
**Why does it work on my home computer and not on our server?**

Also, I've made sure that my Internet Explorer > Internet Options match for both my home computer and the server. I've additionally turned off IE Enhanced Protected Mode on the server.

Is there another setting somewhere that would prevent the save dialog box (see pic attached) from appearing like it does on a normal home computer running Windows 8.1?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Save Dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, in case anyone needs this in the future. It ended up being a Group Policy Object that was overriding the Internet Options.

Comment: Group Policy Object. More information here: http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/Group-Policy-Object